# How do I move money from one address to another on the same wallet?

Tags: wallet

My wallet have 3 addresses. I want to consolidate payment into one.

What should I do in bitcoin-qt.

Notice on the SAME wallet. I know how to do this if the addresses are on different wallet.

I just don't want to keep moving wallets because I have backups on those wallets.

Comment: I disagree with the close vote because this question is geared toward the client, not toward a brain wallet, even though the solution is the same.

Comment: The motivation for the question is different, but the question is the same.  I will edit the other question to make the title more general.

Comment: I think this person is just confused about the meaning of having multiple addresses in his wallet ...

Comment: Yea what does it mean anyway? It's the addresses that hold the money, not the wallet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new address and send your entire balance to that new address.

Comment: Yes, whether the addresses are on the same or different wallet, the technique is the same.